# How to reposition my endless runner game world every 1000 units to prevent float overflow in Unity using C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I heard that generally it is a good idea in an endless runner to reset game world to origin once player goes further and further away from origin. I am currently making an endless runner and want to incorporate this but not sure how to do it. How can I reposition my game every 1000 units?

Not sure which part of my game code will help for answering the question so I am posting most of my code (Hope that is okay). If more information is needed (Such as editor stuff), please let me know. Also if there is anything I can do better code wise then please me know that also. I'd really appreciate that. Thanks!

CameraController.cs

```
public Transform player;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, player.transform.position.z);
    }
```

PlayerController.cs

```
private Vector3 startPos;
private Vector3 endPos;

[SerializeField] private float currentSpeed;
[SerializeField] private float targetSpeed;
[SerializeField] private float acceleration;

private static bool isDead = false;
public GameOverMenu gameOverMenu;

public CameraShake cameraShake;

private int maxRightX = 4;
private int maxLeftX = -4;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    isDead = false;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (isDead)
        return;

    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * currentSpeed);

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        startPos = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        endPos = Input.mousePosition;

        Swipe();
    }

    if (currentSpeed < targetSpeed)
        currentSpeed += Time.deltaTime * acceleration;
}

void Swipe()
{
    Vector2 distance = endPos - startPos;
    if(Mathf.Abs(distance.x) > Mathf.Abs(distance.y))
    {
        if(distance.x > 0 && transform.position.x < maxRightX)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 2.0f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }
        else if (distance.x < 0 && transform.position.x > maxLeftX)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - 2.0f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }
    }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Obstacle"))
    {
        Death();
    }
}

private void Death()
{
    StartCoroutine(cameraShake.Shake(0.2f, 0.2f));
    isDead = true;
    gameOverMenu.ToggleGameOverMenu();
}
```

GroundManager.cs

```
public GameObject groundPrefab;

private Transform playerTransform;
private float spawnZ = -15.0f;
private float groundLength = 15.0f;
private int numofGroundOnScreen = 5;

private List<GameObject> activeGrounds = new List<GameObject>();

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    playerTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;

    for(int i = 0; i < numofGroundOnScreen; i++)
    {
        SpawnGround();
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(playerTransform.position.z - groundLength * 2 > (spawnZ - numofGroundOnScreen * groundLength))
    {
        SpawnGround();
        RemoveGround();
    }
}

private void SpawnGround()
{
    GameObject go;
    go = Instantiate(groundPrefab);
    activeGrounds.Add(go);
    go.transform.SetParent(transform);
    go.transform.position = new Vector3(go.transform.position.x, -0.5f, spawnZ);
    spawnZ += groundLength;
}

private void RemoveGround()
{
    Destroy(activeGrounds[0]);
    activeGrounds.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

EnemyManager.cs

```
public GameObject enemy;

private Transform playerTransform;
private float spawnZ = 25.0f;
private float rateOfSpawn;
private float nextSpawn = 0;
int[] posXList = new int[] { -4,-2, 0, 2, 4 };

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    playerTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    rateOfSpawn = Random.Range(0.5f, 1.0f);

    if (Time.time > nextSpawn)
    {
        nextSpawn = Time.time + rateOfSpawn;
        EnemySpawn();
    }

}

void EnemySpawn()
{
    GameObject go;
    go = Instantiate(enemy);
    go.transform.SetParent(transform);
    int index = Random.Range(0, posXList.Length);
    int randPositionX = posXList[index];
    go.transform.position = new Vector3(randPositionX, 0, playerTransform.position.z + spawnZ);
   
}
```

Comment: I don't really have a fix for your current issue. But a suggestion that instead of moving your player through the world, why not move your world past the player, so the player always stays at `x0`. Then this becomes quite simple where when assets go past `x-100` despawn, and then spawn your enemies at `x100` that way everything is always static.

Comment: @Zze is right. Every 2d endless runner made in this way. You can watch flappy bird making videos for reference. Just move your sprites related to world

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. Thanks for the suggestion! But I'd still prefer to be able to atleast understand how to reset the game world for now if done my way of actually moving the player.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really looking to move the player rather than the world, you could try using transform.SetParent() to temporarily attach your ground (any anything else that needs to stay still in relation to the player) to the player.  If you arrange the hierarchy right, you can probably then move the player to origin, and finally detach the ground and other components.

If you were doing this in a method whenever the player gets 1000+ units from origin, you might be able do this transition smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the idea of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66096300/7111561) the code might look like this e.g. in `PlayerController`

```
[SerializeField] private float resetThreshold = 1000;

void Update()
{  
    ...

    if(Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x) > resetThreshold)
    {
        ResetWorlsPosition();
    }
}

private void ResetWorldPosition()
{
    // First get all root gameObjects of all scenes
    // Remember their original scene, we need that later
    var sceneByRootObject = new Dictionary<Transform, Scene>();
   
    for (var i = 0; i < SceneManager.sceneCount; i++)
    {
        // Get loaded scene by load index
        var scene = SceneManager.GetSceneAt(i);
        // Iterate through all root objects
        foreach(var root in scene.GetRootGameObjects())
        {
            // Store the root and to which scene it belongs
            sceneByRootObject.Add(root, scene);            
        }
    }

    // Iterate through them and make them all a child of the player (this) object
    // keeping their current transforms     
    foreach (var root in rootObjects.Keys)
    {
        // Skip the player root
        if(root == transform.root) continue;

        root.SetParent(transform);
    }

    // Reset player position
    transform.position = Vector3.zero;

    // Unparent all objects moving them again to their original scenes
    foreach (var kvp in rootObjects)
    {
        var root = kvp.Key;

        // Again skip the player root
        if(root == transform.root) continue;

        var scene = kvp.Value;

        // Unparent (now it is a root again)
        root.SetParent(null);
        // Move it back to the correct scene
        SceneManager.MoveObjectToScene(root, scene);
    }
}
```

But it depends of course on you project's requirements. This might e.g. cause hickups in the physics or behave unexpected for Screenspace overlay UI.